# How do I write a labelede list with cross references to the list items?

Tags: cross-referencing, lists, description

I would like to write a labeled list and refer to items in it from elsewhere in the document. My first thought was to use the description environment and the \label tag, but that doesn't seem to work.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[colorlinks,hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage{showlabels}
\showlabels{cite}
\showlabels{cref}
\showlabels{crefrange}

\begin{document}
\begin{description}
\item [Open cover] Foo is an open cover for bar. Note that it need
not be a basis for $S$.
\label{mod:cover}

\item [Closed] Foo is closed under finite intersections.
\label{mod:closed}

\item [Continuous] The morphisms of foo are continuous functions in
bar.

\label{mod:continuous}

\item [Restriction]
\label{mod:rest}
If $f: A \to B$ is a morphism, $A' \subseteq A$,
$B' \subseteq B$ and $f[A'] \subseteq B'$ then
$f \restriction_{A'} : A' \to B'$ is a morphism.
\label{mod:restriction}

\item [Inclusion] If $A' \subseteq A$ then
the inclusion map $i: A' \hookrightarrow A$ is a morphism.
\label{mod:inclusion}

\item [Restricted sheaf condition]
Informally, consistent morphisms can be glued together. Whenever
\begin{enumerate}
\item $U_\alpha$ and $V_\alpha$, $\alpha \prec A$,
are objects of foo.
\item $f_\alpha: U_\alpha \to V_\alpha$ are morphisms of foo.
\item
$U = \bigcup_{\alpha \prec A} {U_\alpha} \in foo$.
\item
$V = \bigcup_{\alpha \prec A} {V_\alpha} \in bar$.
\item
$f: U \to V$ is a continuous function and
for every $\alpha \prec A$,
$f$ agrees with $f_\alpha$ on $U_\alpha$
\end{enumerate}
then $f$ is a morphism of $foo$.
\label{mod:sheaf}
\end{description}

Test cref\{mod:closed\}: \cref{mod:closed}

Test autoref\{mod:closed\}: \autoref{mod:closed}

Test refname\{mod:closed\}: \refname{mod:closed}
\end{document}
```

does not produce

```
Test cref{mod:closed}: item Closed
Test autoref{mod:closed}: item Closed
Test refname{mod:closed}: Closed
```

or anything similar.

Comment: A `\label` is usually connected to a counter -- `description` does not use or display counter values, so there is nothing what `\label` can get grip of! What shall displayed as cross-referencing information? The literal names of the items, i.e. `Restriction` etc.?

Comment: @Christian Hupfer That's why I'm asking about alternatives. I'm looking for tags that let me make a list in which each entry has descriptive text and in which some entries also have names that can be used to retrieve the associated descriptive text and page

Comment: I might have a solution for you, but it will not co-operate with `showlabels`, i.e. showlabels won't show such labels (most likely)

Comment: @Christian I'd be interested in seeing your solution even if showlabels doesn't support it. Thanks.

Comment: I have to work on some issues. I still think that it is possible, but it requires a little bit of programming